# Can't get right meaning of the sentence

Tags: verbs, tenses, verb-forms

I have an exercise as follows.

I must .......... .

1. my car have repaired
2. my car be repaired
3. have my car repaired
4. repaired

Can't get correct meaning of the sentence. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are saying that they require repairs to be performed on their car.

The correct answer to the question is number 3 as the verbs have and be always go before the object in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"To have something done" as in "We had our car repaired." is a tricky grammatical structure because it combines the verb have in an active form – active simple past "We had" – and a past participle, which is what is left of a passive bare infinitive (passive infinitive without "to") "our car (be) repaired".

> to have someone do something for you

*active "have" and active bare infinitive "do"*

> to have something be done for you by someone

*active "have" and passive bare infinitive "be done": the object of the active bare infinitive has become the subject of the passive bare infinitive*

> to have something done

*"be" is dropped, and so are "for you" and "by someone"*

But I am surprised you have not been redirected to ELL, English Language Learners…